# Multiple input checks, repeat if conditions are not met

Tags: go, input

I've already posted this on [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255840/multiple-input-checks-repeat-if-conditions-are-not-met) where is more appropriate I believe, but didn't get any feedback, so I'm posting it here where there's probably greater audience.

I've used this code to make some inputs checks. On any failed check, I need to ask again for proper input. I used `labels` and `goto` to achieve this, which they seem to be disliked by programmers as a concept.

How could I achieve the same effect without labels/goto? I considered putting all this code in a function and calling itself from inside, but it repeated only once for some reason - didn't keep asking if kept getting wrong answers.

```golang
// 0 exits
var f float64
var n int
startGame := func() {
reception:
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Print(`Give number (1-9): `)
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&f)

    // check letters or symbols
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Letters or symbols not accepted")
        goto reception
    }

    // exit
    if f == 0 {
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    // check for integers only
    if f < 1 || f > 9 || f-math.Ceil(f) != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Only integer numbers between 1-9 are accepted")
        goto reception
    }

    n = int(f)
    // check for empty cells
    if myArray[n-1] == false {
        fmt.Println("Empty cell", n)
        goto reception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `for {}` `continue` and `break` it if evrything is good. like this:

```golang
    startGame := func() {
        for {
            fmt.Println()
            fmt.Print(`Give number (1-9): `)
            _, err := fmt.Scan(&f)

            // check letters or symbols
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Letters or symbols not accepted")
                continue
            }

            // exit
            if f == 0 {
                os.Exit(0)
            }

            // check for integers only
            if f < 1 || f > 9 || f-math.Ceil(f) != 0 {
                fmt.Println("Only integer numbers between 1-9 are accepted")
                continue
            }

            if !true {
                fmt.Println("Empty cell", n)
                continue
            }
            break
        }
    }
    startGame()
    fmt.Println("good luck! bye.")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var f float64 = math.MaxFloat32
var n int
for ;f!=0; {
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Print(`Give number (1-9): `)
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&f)
    // check letters or symbols
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Letters or symbols not accepted")
        continue
    }
    // check for integers only
    if f < 1 || f > 9 || f-math.Ceil(f) != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Only integer numbers between 1-9 are accepted")
        continue
    }

    n = int(f)
    // check for empty cells
    if f > 0 && myArray[n-1] == false {
        fmt.Println("Empty cell", n)
    }
}
```

Also all the above if conditions can be made as `else if`s as well. Or you can either use continue.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to using a loop, you can make it a recursive function. I don't know what you did when you apparently  tried doing it like this, but this should work as expected.

```
func startGame() {
    var f float64
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Print("Give number (1-9): ")
    _, err := fmt.Scan(&f)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Letters or symbols not accepted")
        startGame()
    }
    if f == 0 {
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    if f < 1 || f > 9 || f-math.Ceil(f) != 0 {
        fmt.Println("Only integer numbers between 1-9 are accepted")
        startGame()
    }
    n := int(f)
    if myArray[n-1] == false {
        fmt.Println("Empty cell", int(f))
        startGame()
    }
}

func main() {
    startGame()
    fmt.Println("good luck! bye.")
}
```